# Visual C++ Windows add data firebase database

Tags: c++, rest, put

When I look for this online, the only way I see is to use chillkat, which requires api key.

I got this working once in C# but can't remember how I did it.

I think if I can find a way to send a PUT request in C++ it will be ok, but again, I can't find a simple way to add curl to a standalone windows project.

Any help appreciated, I just need to write to the database, not read it.

Comment: For a quick solution on Windows, search for "http post with wininet".

Comment: thanks, I ended up just silently running a cmd command to silently run a powershell script to run a dynamically generated script to post the data, since it doens't have to be done often, but your solution is way better

Comment: @rustyx please make an answer so I can mark it